# How to swap ETH with WETH using UniswapV2?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js, uniswap

I'm trying to swap ETH for its equivalent in WETH using UniswapRouterV2 and ethers.js but I don't know what address to put in as ETH in the path array since it doesn't have one, so please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    await this.uniswapRouter.swapETHForExactTokens(
        ethers.provider.getBalance(attacker.addres), // amountOut
        [0, this.weth.address], // path: what should it be instead of 0?
        attacker.address, // to
        (await ethers.provider.getBlock('latest').timestamp) * 2, // deadline
        {value: ethers.provider.getBalance(attacker.addres)} // msg.value
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Just got it. It was so simple and the UniswapRouterV2 contract was not needed at all. One has to execute the deposit function of WETH contract and the contract gives ETH back. Something like this:

```
 await this.weth.connect(attacker).deposit({value: ethToWETHAmount})
```